# Something's wrong with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, hyphenation, babel, tocloft

I want the right margin of TOC to be straight. Instead of this Latex violates the bound (Pic. 1). If babel is commented out (with the last \addcontentsline), the result is still buggy (Pic. 2). Apparently, some of the words could be carried over to the next lines even without hyphenation.

Here is the minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\cftsetrmarg{4cm}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted  Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted }

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom test test test blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Численные исследования разработанных алгоритмов}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pic. 1]

**Picture 1 (above).**

[image: Pic. 2]

**Picture 2 (above).**

**UPDATE.**

The proposed solutions partially solved the problem. The remaining problems are shown on the  Picture 3. The corresponding code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% Compulsory settings
\textwidth=170mm
\cftsetrmarg{6.35cm}

% Adviced (but not working) options
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\penalty5000 \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\emergencystretch=10em
\sloppy


\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This line just demonstrates the right bound. Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted  Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted }

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Thisline demonstratesdemonstrates thewidthof posbbbbbbbbbbbbbbblegaps. Thisline demonstrates thewidthof possiblegaps.}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Parameter parmeter parameter parammmeter Fibre Channel}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pic. 3]

**Picture 3 (above).**

Comment: If there are not feasible hyphenation points, your `\sloppy` declaration will let TeX produce awful paragraphs. A "real world" example would be better.

Comment: egreg, the erroneous is the third toc entry, not the second one.

Comment: There's *no* way to typeset that paragraph with the given constraints. It happens; that's why I asked for a real example.

Comment: I'm talking about the last paragraph that is violated the red line.  It should be hyphenated in the following way: Chan-nel, and the 'nel' should be carried over to the next line.

Comment: No: the text in the last line is allowed to go beyond that red line, with your setting.

Comment: And I need to prohibit such behaviour. That's exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically I think your requirement is that the leaders are *at least* `\rightskip` in length and they never shrink less than that, so allowing the last line to extend.

So you need a modified leaders command that always inserts at least that many dots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% Compulsory settings
\textwidth=170mm
\cftsetrmarg{6.35cm}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\cftdotfillb}[1]{%
  \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern #1 mu\hbox{\cftdot}\mkern #1 mu$}\hskip 1\rightskip plus 1fill}

% Adviced (but not working) options
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfillb{\cftdotsep}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

\sloppy
\emergencystretch3em

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{This line just demonstrates the right bound. Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted  Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted }

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Thisline demonstratesdemonstrates thewid\-thof pos\-bbbbb\-bb\-bbbbbbbblegaps. Thisline demonstrates thewidthof possiblegaps.}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Parameter parmeter parameter parammmeter Fibre Channel}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Parameter parmeter  Fibre Channel}

\end{document}
```

---

Original answer

I'm not sure it's really babel; I seem not to have the babel cyrilic support installed so couldn't duplicate all your cases but the repeated bbb case can be demonstrated even if babel isn't loaded at all.

The line breaks better for reasons I haven't had time to trace fully if you allow but strongly discourage a break before the leader

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\penalty5000 \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked almost perfectly: "bbbbbb" went away to a new line. But a small overfull (see Picture 2, the last word "blos-") still remains.

Comment: That's a rather different issue, the unnatural text in the example can't be hyphenated to avoid an overfull box using English (or looking at your input) Russian hyphenation.  You could allow the white space to stretch more using \sloppy or a finer tuned setting of \emergencystretch, but in your real example using a language setting suitable for the actual text should give better line breaks. For this example adding `\hyphenation{blo-s-s-om}` to the preamble allows blossom to hyphenate as blo-ssom and so avoid the over full line with `s` sticking out.

Comment: David, Look at the 'Update' section of the question above. a) The word combination 'Fibre Channel' is natural and easy to hyphenate. b) \sloppy and \emergencystretch=10em are on. c) Note that 10em is a rather big value what is demonstrated by the second toc entry. It is more than enough to carry over the whole word 'Channel' to the next line without even hyphenating it. d) Hyphenation is on. Nothing prevents Latex to hyphenate 'Channel' and meet the bound.

Comment: I may look if I have time later but the real problem is that tocloft (which I have never used before) just is not doing the design that you want. It sets things such that all lines _except the last_ have the large right margin, and the last line is allowed to stretch to the end, with .... if needed. thus the last line sticking out is not a bug but a design. Sticking in a penalty sometimes breaks that design and gives you something closer to what you want but probably doing it properly means not using or makeing bigger changes to tocloft

Comment: You can force it to take a line longer by `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\penalty500 \aftergroup\looseness\aftergroup1\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` but then it always does it even for very short entries, so you mught prefer to just drop in the looseness control by hand when needed

Comment: Tocloft sets the same margins **for all lines**. It doesn't allow the last line to stretch to the end. You can be convinced of this if you increase the right margin by 0.05cm (change \cftsetrmarg{6.35cm} to \cftsetrmarg{6.4cm}). The last word will be carried over.

Comment: You are mistaken. It defines `\parfillskip -\rightskip` which means that the last line sticks out by the full amount of `\rightskip` this space may be filled either with text from the entry or with leaders. that is why in all your pictures eg the last three lines in your picture 1 in the original question the last line of each entry is long. The fact that earlier lines stick out is different they are overfull boxes caused by using unhyphenatable words, which `\sloppy` tries to avoid. The code in the updated answer should do what you need.

Comment: It's perfect for `\cftsetrmarg`'s down to `{1.32cm}` but it's buggy for `\cftsetrmarg{1.31cm}`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3710/discussion-between-ivan-bychkov-and-david-carlisle)

Answer (score 5):

Switch to the correct language and modify `\emergencystretch`. However, you shouldn't set `cftsetrmarg`. Using the default value gives a better result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\cftsetrmarg{4cm}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\emergencystretch=2em
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted  Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted }}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{Blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom test test test blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom}}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\foreignlanguage{english}{Bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb}}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Численные исследования разработанных алгоритмов}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, \cftsetrmarg{4cm} was used just for example. And \emergencystretch=2em doesn't solve the problem of the last "bbbbbb" and "алгоритмов".

Comment: sure, that is the default of tocleft.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that space from the right side is added to the toc entry only in the case if it spans more than one line, so your example is probably fine.

If you really want all lines with same width, you can use solution provided by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58781/2891)

In case if you have multiline entries in Russian and English, you should manually select correct language with `\selectlanguage` to enable the hyphenation. See `\selectlanguage{russian}` before russian contents entry.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\cftsetrmarg{4cm}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted  Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted }

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom test test test blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom blossom}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb}
\selectlanguage{russian}

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Численные исследования разработанных алгоритмов Численные исследования разработанных алгоритмов Численные исследования разработанных алгоритмов}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about slight overfull in your solution for "blos-" and "иссле-"?